# Parâmetros nulos no controller ao enviar post via ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Estou refatorando uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC escrita por outro desenvolvedor. Minha intenção é remover o uso de `FormCollection`.

Antes a assinatura do método do controller era a seguinte:

```
public ActionResult Salvar(FormCollection ParametroformCollection, FormCollection ParametroFormHidden, string ParametroView, string ParametroStrDirecao)
```

O envio dos formulários era feito via ajax, utilizando `serializeArray()`

Então criei dois models, um para cada formulário, porém no controller os objetos não são preenchidos, ficando nulos. Tentei serializar com `serializeArray()` e com `serialize()`. Não sei porque não está dando certo.

**HTML dos Formulários**

```
<form id="hiddenForms" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="idhiddenFormPlaca" name="namehiddenFormPlaca" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="idhiddenFormFabricante" name="namehiddenFormFabricante" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="idhiddenFormAnoModelo" name="namehiddenFormAnoModelo" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="idhiddenFormOficina" name="namehiddenFormOficina" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="idhiddenFormCarrinho" name="namehiddenFormCarrinho" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="idhiddenFormAlteracao" name="namehiddenFormAlteracao" value="" />
</form>

<form id="containerForm" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="idPlaca" name="namePlaca" value="@Model.strPlacaVeiculo" />
    <div class="radio" style="display:none;">
        <label><input type="radio" id="idRbCarros" name="optradio" value="Carros e Utilitários Pequenos">Carros</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio" style="display:none;">
        <label><input type="radio" id="idRbMotos" name="optradio" value="Motos">Motos</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio" style="display:none;">
        <label><input type="radio" id="idRbCaminhoes" name="optradio" value="Caminhões e Micro-Ônibus">Caminhões</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript do envio**

```
function enviar() {
     var form = $("#containerForm").serialize();
     var formhidden = $("#hiddenForms").serialize();
     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Salvar", "Home")',
                data: { ParametroformCollection: form, ParametroFormHidden: formhidden, ParametroView: "Placa", ParametroStrDirecao: ParametroDirecao },
                success: function (result) {

                }
     });
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Salvar(PlacaForm ParametroformCollection, FormHidden ParametroFormHidden, string ParametroView, string ParametroStrDirecao)
    {
      ....
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class FormHidden
{
    public string namehiddenFormPlaca { get; set; }
    public string namehiddenFormFabricante { get; set; }
    public string namehiddenFormAnoModelo { get; set; }
    public string namehiddenFormOficina { get; set; }
    public string namehiddenFormCarrinho { get; set; }
    public string namehiddenFormAlteracao { get; set; }
}

public class PlacaForm
{
    public string namePlaca { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Os `form` para funcionarem ficaram assim:

*Observação:* colocado nos campos do formulário, os seus valores.

```
<form id="hiddenForms" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="idhiddenFormPlaca" name="namehiddenFormPlaca" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" id="idhiddenFormFabricante" name="namehiddenFormFabricante" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" id="idhiddenFormAnoModelo" name="namehiddenFormAnoModelo" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" id="idhiddenFormOficina" name="namehiddenFormOficina" value="3" />
    <input type="hidden" id="idhiddenFormCarrinho" name="namehiddenFormCarrinho" value="4" />
    <input type="hidden" id="idhiddenFormAlteracao" name="namehiddenFormAlteracao" value="5" />
</form>

<form id="containerForm" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="namePlaca" name="namePlaca" value="100" />
    <div class="radio" style="display:none;">
        <label><input type="radio" id="idRbCarros" name="optradio" value="Carros e Utilitários Pequenos">Carros</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio" style="display:none;">
        <label><input type="radio" id="idRbMotos" name="optradio" value="Motos">Motos</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio" style="display:none;">
        <label><input type="radio" id="idRbCaminhoes" name="optradio" value="Caminhões e Micro-Ônibus">Caminhões</label>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="enviarData()">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

No código `Javascript`, deve enviar um item **serializado** com todas as informações, então, foi feita a junção dos dois `form`:

```
function enviarData() {

    var data = $("#hiddenForms").serialize();
    data = data + "&" + $("#containerForm").serialize();

    //console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Salvar", "Home")',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        "error": function (result) {
            var response = result.responseText;
            alert('Erro: ' + response);
        }
    });
}
```

No botão de envio, no *evento* `onClick` eu passei o nome da função `enviarData();`, e por fim no `controller`:

```
[HttpPost()]
public ActionResult Salvar(FormHidden formHidden, PlacaForm placaForm)
{
   //code ...
}
```

Comment: Deu certo não. Ainda os models ficaram nulos.

Comment: @Murilo dá uma olhada no seu Javascript e compare! o código acima é testado. olha na parte `$.ajax`!